# Include all files under a folder

Tags: java, jsp

i have a folder of javascript files, is it possible to include all of the files under that folder automatically? something like

```
<jsp:include-all parentFolder='/javascript' extension='.js' />
```

OK to make it clear

i have an ajax application, with lots of js fragments, but i want to aggregate all of them into one big js file so to speed up application loading

now what i am doing is using <%@include .... %> to manually include all the js files

every time i change a js file name or add / remove js file, i have to come back the aggregation jsp file to edit it

Comment: Adding "[jsp]" at the beginning is not how tag this question with the jsp tag. You should be able to edit and change the title to "Include all files under a folder in JSP" or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Use [YUI compressor](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/) and a shot of simple [`java.io`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/io/) code to minify and combine multiple Javascript files into a single file right *before* deploy. You don't want to do this on **every** request.

Comment: That's great for production, but for development I prefer to have separate files.

Comment: @WojciechGórski: just run it during production only.

Comment: And what do I include in development then?

Comment: @WojciechGórski: uh, just separate files the usual way and don't run YUI compressor? What exactly didn't you understand from the answer? YUI compresser is a build tool, not a runtime tool.

Comment: So basically you're suggesting to write something like `<jsp:include-all parentFolder='/javascript' extension='.js' />` ?